# Netatalk disk not shown in TimeMachine, manual connect via afp works

Tags: backup, time-machine, unix, afp

I set up netatalk on Ubuntu to backup via TimeMachine to one partition there over my network. I can connect to the partition through the Finder `Go...` menue. But I cannot see an option to create a new folder. In TimeMachine this backup disk does not show up.

I tried using [this Ubuntuusers' wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/netatalk/#Freigabe-fuer-Apple-Time-Machine) for netatalk v2 and using [these instructions](http://netatalk.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Install_Netatalk_3.1.12_on_Ubuntu_18.04_Bionic) for netatalk v3. None works. I suspect a problem with my MacOS but don't know where to search. How can I make the backup disk visible to TimeMachine?

Comment: Does the share/drive show up in the TimeMachine preferences when it is mounted in Finder?

Comment: Unfortunately it does not

Answer (score 4):

I've recently had the same experience.  Netatalk exported a volume with time machine set to yes, I could mount the volume, but it would not show up in the Time Machine preferences panel.

From the Finder I tried to create a new file/folder and realized that I didn't have write permissions.  Granting read/write permissions on the underlying volume on the file server then allowed Time Machine to find it.

The specifics of how to change permissions will vary but I changed ownership (chown) and permissions (chmod) on the mount point on the file server.